# Python: get the current channel of WiFi interface

Tags: python, wifi, channel

how're you doing?

I am trying to find a simple way to get the channel of a wifi interface. Well, I found a way to do so, but it's pretty messed up and not simple at all. I've searched the internet, but nobody seems to have the same problem.

**Here is how I do it:**

I take the output of `iwlist wlan0 channel` which is:

```
wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
```

You can clearly see the channel (currently Channel 4).

I'm using the `subprocess`-module to get the output:

```
stdout = Popen('iwlist ' + iface + ' channel', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
output = stdout.read()
channel = output[-5:-3].replace(' ', '')
```

The output is exactly what I want, but the way to get it is too complicated. I also don't want to use any shell commands...

Is there another way? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [python-wifi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-wifi):

```
from pythonwifi.iwlibs import Wireless

wifi = Wireless('wlan0')
num_frequencies, channels = wifi.getChannelInfo()
current_freq = wifi.getFrequency()
# Only for 2.4 GHz
print channels.index(current_freq) + 1
```

Comment: That's way more comfortable! Thank you:)